# Combination of three vocabulary sets

Tags: python

"Core", "advanced", "extra" are sets of vocabulary for those who study a foreign language. A user has to choose one, two or all three sets.

I would like to get all possible combinations:

```
from itertools import product

variants = list(product([0, 1], repeat=3))
variants.remove((0, 0, 0)) # In this case a validation exception is risen.
print(list(variants))

sample = ["core", "advanced", "extra",]

result = []

for variant in variants:
    tmp = []
    for i in range(3):
        if variant[i]:
            tmp.append(sample[i])
    result.append(tmp)
print (result)
```

The result is achieved. But could you tell me whether my code can be written more elegantly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would go with the `itertools.compress` method where:

```None
compress('ABCDEF', [1,0,1,0,1,1]) --> A C E F
```

Then your code becomes:

```py
from itertools import compress, product

variants = list(product([0, 1], repeat=3))
variants.remove((0, 0, 0)) # At least one type of vocabulary must be selected

sample = ["core", "advanced", "extra",]

result = list(list(compress(sample, variant)) for variant in variants)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```None
[['extra'], ['advanced'], ['advanced', 'extra'], ['core'], ['core', 'extra'], ['core', 'advanced'], ['core', 'advanced', 'extra']]
```

Answer (score 1):

`print(list(variants))` could be simply `print(variants)` since it's already a list.  But I don't see why we're printing this: what's the value to the user?

We can avoid the magic number `3`, replacing with `len(sample)`.  Now our code magically adapts if we add another category.

---

Rather than `itertools.product()` and post-processing, we could get what we want using `itertools.combinations()` choosing 1, 2 and 3 values from the list.  Then join the results into a single list using `chain.from_iterable()`:

```
def all_nonempty_subsets(values):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable((itertools.combinations(values, x+1))
                                          for x in range(len(values)))
```

Then we can print these combinations like this:

```
print('\n'.join(map(str, all_nonempty_subsets(["core", "advanced", "extra",]))))
```

Or perhaps with a `for` loop:

```
for choice in all_nonempty_subsets(["core", "advanced", "extra",]):
    print(', '.join(choice))
```